# iphone- [AVAssetReaderAudioMixOutput copyNextSampleBuffer] Error

Tags: iphone

I am working with AVAssetReader and AVAssetWriter to make movie with multi tracks.
So I finished it using [AVAssetReaderAudioMixOutput copyNextSampleBuffer] and [AVAssetWriterInput appendSampleBuffer].

But I kept getting the error: [AVAssetReaderTrackOutput copyNextSampleBuffer] cannot copy next sample buffer unless the asset reader is in the 'reading' state'.
How solve this problem.

Comment: Also, check that writer.inputs and reader.outputs are correct

Answer (score 2):

```
MPMediaQuery *meidaQuery = [[[MPMediaQuery alloc] init] autorelease];
MPMediaItem *mediaItem = [[meidaQuery items] objectAtIndex:0];
AVURLAsset *urlAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[mediaItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL] options:nil];

AVAssetReader *assetReader = [AVAssetReader assetReaderWithAsset:urlAsset error:nil];
AVAssetTrack *assetTrack = [[urlAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];
AVAssetReaderTrackOutput *assetReaderTrackOutput = [AVAssetReaderTrackOutput assetReaderTrackOutputWithTrack:assetTrack outputSettings:NULL];
[assetReader addOutput:assetReaderTrackOutput];
[assetReader startReading];

CMSampleBufferRef sampleBufferRef = [assetReaderTrackOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];
```